# Magento card number in sales email (first 4)

Tags: magento

When a sales confirmation email is sent to a customer, in the email under the Payment Method section(if they use credit card) it shows xxxx-then the last four digits of there credit card number ex: xxxx-8743

My question is how can I make it show the first 4 and the last 4 of their card number?
ex:5435-8743

This is for magento 1.8.1.0

Comment: You can do it using str_replace.

Comment: I understand the Magento database stores the final four numbers from the credit card and it will store as encrypted in db

Comment: It depends on the payment method - which method are you using?

Comment: This shows in the email if the customer is using a credit card.